# Excel vsto selenium with chrome start button not working

Tags: excel, vb.net, selenium, vsto, office-addins

Hi I have created an excel workbook with vsto. I'm running chrome with Selenium and the web page is opening.
There is no problem in my codes, it works when I test it.
When I press the button when I publish the project, nothing happens.
What could be the problem?

> 

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports System.Text

Public Module Test
    Sub Main()
        Dim driver As IWebDriver
        driver = New ChromeDriver
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com")

    End Sub




End Module
```

Chrome won't open when I press the button.

Comment: Try adding any logging statements to the code to see what is going on under the hood.

Comment: After doing some research, I found this page.
I guess the problem is that the webdriver doesn't load when I publish the project.
How can I get the webdriver to load when I publish the project.
https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/ooP6V7xDmJk/m/a2t2FTovBAAJ

Comment: It makes sense. Do you get any exceptions at runtime in that case?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I don't get any errors at runtime.